# textrm is not displaying certain characters

Tags: urls

I am trying to make a web URL display in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
\subsection{test}
\label{sec:test}

    [0] "test" $\emph{test}$. test, test. $\textrm{<http://tex.stackexchange.com/>}$. \\
\end{document}
```

But everything shows up except that URL. Are there certain characters restricted even for `textrm`? I thought `textrm` displayed any character like it normally would with regular text.

Comment: Use the package `url` which provides the command `\url{}`. Also, don't use dollar sign if the content is not mathematical.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The `hyperref´ package is another alternative that provides clickable links in pdf.

Comment: Okay, I got /url{} working, but the font is different from the other text which all needs to be the same font. I am going to print this out for a report so it doesn't have to be clickable, but also I can't get the brackets <> around the URL to show up, even with using a backslash to try and escape the bracket characters.

Comment: @guest56423 I think it is a convention to have the urls in a "computerish" font. I think, your demand is best met as:  `\texttt{<http://tex.stackexchange.com/>}`.

Answer (score 6):

```
 $\textrm{<http://tex.stackexchange.com/>}$
```

You don't want math mode there, it is doing nothing other than slowing down the processing as `\textrm` gets you back to text mode. The `<` and `>` do not show up as the expected symbols as you are using the classic `OT1` TeX encoding. You could use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to use an 8bit encoding in which the ASCII characters are in the usual slots but even if using that it is generally better to use `\url` from the `url` package or `hyperref` as that allows line breaking in a URL-aware manner, you can issue the command

```
\urlstyle{rm}
```

to make `\url` use the same font as `\textrm`.

Answer (score 5):

You could load the LaTeX package called `url` and issue the command `\urlstyle{same}` in the document's preamble. That way, all material contained in various `\url{....}` directives will be typeset in current text font.

A big plus of using the `\url` directive for typesetting URL strings is that LaTeX will (generally) do a good job finding permissible line breaks in long URL strings.

**Addendum**:
If you want to include "less than" and "greater than" signs at the start and end of a URL string, @GonzaloMedina has pointed out that one can do so nicely by loading the `textcomp` package and using that package's commands `\textless` and `\textgreater`. For instance, the code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{textcomp,url} 
\urlstyle{same} 
\newcommand\myurl[1]{\textless\url{#1}\textgreater} 
\begin{document} 
\myurl{http://tex.stackexchange.com/} 
\end{document}
```

generates:

[image]

Comment: With `url`’s own command and assuming David Carlisles advice with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is applied: `\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>}\urlstyle{same}}`. But I would actually prefer `\urlstyle{tt}` or `\urlstyle{sf}` for better distinction.

Comment: @Speravir - thanks for this. The OP had mentioned in one of the comments that he/she wants the URLs to be typeset in the same font as the surrounding text, so that's why I'm setting `\urlstyle{same}`...